# Issue loading a favicon.ico file in a web page

Tags: php, html, favicon

I have an issue with the *favicon.ico* file on a web page (*mypage.php*).

The following code works (using the Firefox browser), the icon appears as expected in the tab:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

But as soon as I insert the code below (which I further need) in the body of the page:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
?>
```

I get the following problem in the logs:

```
GET https://www.example.net/favicon.ico
Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at https://www.example.net/favicon.ico (“default-src”).
```

Can someone explain why I have this issue and how I should solve it?

The first point puzzling me is that the error message refers to a favicon.ico at the root directory of the web site while the <link rel=".." ...> line is only trying to use the favicon.ico file in the local directory where mypage.php resides.

Comment: Why would a JSON file need a favicon? Also, I’d inspect the headers being sent for any CSP.

Comment: Actually I agree, I have no need for a favicon. I just put a favicon because I see this message showing up complaining about a missing favicon. That's all. I may be doing something wrong doing that ...